# iOS - How To Remove Previously Added Sublayers Of a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I have a custom view which is a subclass of `UIView`. I added some sublayers to the custom view but now I want remove them.

I tried doing this:

```
self.layer.sublayers = nil;
```

But this will remove everything including the initial sublayers of the view.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or do I have to reinitialise a new custom view every time?

*Note: App runs in iOS 7 and above.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Keep a reference to the sublayer added
Remove the sublayer from the super layer when not needed.

The code would be like:

Obj C:

```
[thesublayer removeFromSuperlayer]
```

Swift:

```
thesublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

//thesublayer is the name of the layer you want to remove
```

Comment: Why didn't I thought of this... -_- Thanks!

Answer (score 64):

Another way to remove specific layer from super layer is to assign unique string in `layer.name` property. Which you can compare later to identify and remove it out.

```
for layer in sublayers {
     if layer.name == "masklayer" {
          layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 20):

keeping reference is not cool, in some cases you can use

```
resultImageView.layer.sublayers?.filter{ $0 is CAShapeLayer }.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```

or to be more generic by using CALayer, which removes everything

Comment: All other solutions crashed me - this one worked thank you!

Answer (score 19):

I did it in Swift 3 using [`popLast()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1539777-poplast).

```
self.layer.sublayers?.popLast()
```

Comment: thanks, all the other solutions were crashing when trying to remove sublayer from a a UITextArea in Swift 4

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

first of all you should add a name to the sublayer with `theLayer.name` property

after that you can extend the view like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func removeLayer(layerName: String) {
            for item in self.layer.sublayers ?? [] where item.name == layerName {
                    item.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for removing `AVPlayerLayer` without keeping a reference to it:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // Remove player layer when screen gone
    NSUInteger layerIndex = [self.view.layer.sublayers indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(__kindof CALayer * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        return [obj isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerLayer class]];
    }];
    if (layerIndex != NSNotFound) {
        AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = self.view.layer.sublayers[layerIndex];
        [playerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
view.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```

Answer (score 0):

A blend of the safest answers:

First, set the `name` property on each added sublayer. In this case, adding a `CAShapeLayer`:

```
private let shapeName = "shape"
let shape = ...
shape.name = shapeName
self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
```

Later, remove only those named sublayers:

```
self.layer.sublayers?
    .filter { $0.name == self.shapeName }
    .forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```